# Updating data in a Database

Tags: android, database

My program is about todo list each time I add a task the program should save it in the database.

The problem that I am having is that it does not update the task that I save it previously.

Whenever I login to the app I should find the tasks that I add them to the database.

I couldn't figure out where is the problem.

This is my code:

**Todo** class:

```
public class Todo implements Parcelable 
{
    private String title;
    private String status;
    private String priority;
    private String date;
    private String time;
}
```

**TodoDAO** class:

```
public long updateTodo (Todo todo)
{
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String whereClause = TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " =? " + TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS + " =? "

                             +TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_PRIORITY + " =? "+  TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_DATE+ " =? "

                             +TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME + " =? " ;

        String whereArgu [] =  {todo.getTitle() ,todo.getStatus() , todo.getPriority() , todo.getDate() , todo.getTime() };

        ContentValues values =  changeTodoToContentobject( todo);

        return  db.update(TodoTable.TABLE_NAME , values, whereClause  ,  whereArgu );
}
```

**TodoDBHelper** class:

```
public class TodoDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  implements  Contract
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";

private static final int VERSION = 1;

private static final String SQL_CREATE_TODO_TABLE =
        " CREATE TABLE " + TodoTable.TABLE_NAME +

                " ( " + TodoTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
                      + TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE    + "  TEXT , "+
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS   + "  TEXT , "+
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_PRIORITY + "  TEXT , "+
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_DATE     + "  TEXT , "+
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_NAME_TIME     + " TEXT ); " ;



private static final String SQL_DELETE_TODO_TABLE =
        " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TodoTable.TABLE_NAME +  " ; " ;



public TodoDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TODO_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_TODO_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Interface **Contract**:

```
public interface Contract {

class TodoTable implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "todo";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PRIORITY = "priority";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE= "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIME = "time";
}
```

Comment: Go ahead with this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: In `updateTodo()`, your `WHERE` isn't correct. You're passing the updated values in the `ContentValues`. The only thing the `WHERE` should have is the ID; e.g., `db.update(TodoTable.TABLE_NAME , values, "_id=" + todo.getId(), null)`. If you're not already keeping the ID in your `Todo` class somewhere, you need to change it to do so.

Comment: It's a **column** - not a "coloum" ......